# setting awk variables through inlining

Tags: shell, gawk

I've got this:
./awktest -v fields=`cat testfile`

which ought to set fields variable to '1 2 3 4 5' which is all that testfile contains

It returns:
gawk: ./awktest:9: fatal: cannot open file `2' for reading (No such file or directory)

When I do this it works fine.
./awktest -v fields='1 2 3 4 5'

printing fields at the time of error yields:
1
printing fields in the second instance yields:
1 2 3 4 5

When I try it with 12345 instead of 1 2 3 4 5 it works fine for both, so it's a problem with the white space. What is this problem? And how do I fix it.

Comment: What is in `awktest`?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely not an `awk` question. Most likely, it is your *shell* that is the culprit.

For example, if awktest is:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
for arg in "$@"; do
  printf "%d\t%s\n" $i "$arg"   
  ((i++))
done
```

Then you get:

```
$ ./awktest -v fields=`cat testfile`
1   -v
2   fields=1
3   2
4   3
5   4
6   5
```

You see that the file contents are not being handled as a single word.

Simple solution: use double quotes on the command line:

```
$ ./awktest -v fields="$(< testfile)"
1   -v
2   fields=1 2 3 4 5
```

The `$(< file)` construct is a bash shortcut for `` `cat file` `` that does not need to spawn an external process.

Or, read the first line of the file in the awk BEGIN block

```
awk '
    BEGIN {getline fields < "testfile"} 
    rest of awk program ...
'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
./awktest -v fields="`cat testfile`"

#note that:
#./awktest -v fields='`cat testfile`'
#does not work
```